# Sort order in CMS widget 'Catalog Products List'

Tags: magento2.4

I´ve added a Catalog Product List Block to a CMS page. The list seems to be sorted by category IDs instead of the position values of the products. The source code looks like this:

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="Featured Products" show_pager="0" products_count="99" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`8`^]^]"}}
```

I´ve tried to change *attribute:category_ids* to *attribute:position*, but unfortunately this breaks the rendering of the list widget.
How can I achieve to make the widget rendering the list according to the position of the products in that category?

**EDIT:**
I found this code in the function *createCollection* (vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Block/Product/ProductsList.php, line 344):

```
$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc')
        ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
        ->setCurPage($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getData('page_var_name'), 1));
```

Is there any way to set the sorting attribute to 'position'? I can hardly imagine that it should not be possible to control the order of the article list.
I am grateful for any hint!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not @danronmoon

Comment: For some inexplicable reason sort order algorithms are present in pagebuilder.  If you have that installed it should pick up on that: https://github.com/magento/magento2-page-builder/blob/98b8d2f6137d8f6bc361bc2b8b52d4e68eb67c6b/app/code/Magento/PageBuilder/etc/di.xml#L304